# How to use slugs in RESTful URLs?

Tags: seo, slug, restful-url

According to [current best practices](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) a RESTful URL for a given thread on a message board should look something like this:

```
http://domain/forum/threads/3
```

It is also a common SEO practice that URLs should contain keywords (slug), so perhaps the above URL could become:

```
http://domain/forum/threads/3/title-of-this-particular-thread
```

Now, to edit this thread, again, according to the guidelines I've linked to in the first paragraph, the URL would be:

```
http://domain/forum/threads/3/edit
```

What should happen when someone starts a thread with the title of "edit"? How should it be decided if the thread is to be shown or edited?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `http://domain/forum/threads/3/title-of-this-particular-thread`

You should be doing `http://domain/forum/threads/3-title-of-this-particular-thread`

This will prevent conflicts and is just as SEO friendly. There are a few ways to accomplish this, but the easiest is to add a to_param method in your model that does the conversion automatically:

```
class Thread < ActiveRecord::Base
  to_param
    "#{id}-#{title}"
  end
end
```

If you need more flexibility than this, or don't want to repeat it in all your models, you can use the [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) Gem.

Comment: the URLs on StackOverflow beg to differ